# Windows powering off after "preparing your desktop" stage

Tags: windows-7, windows

Windows 7 64 bit.

The only recent change was I installed two updates for MS Office, and a cumulative security update for IE.

As soon as I choose a user and login, after loading my user profile it states the preparing your desktop message, and then powers off.

I have used DaRT to check the event log, but nothing is recorded.

Ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the win7 recovery? recover the system from befor the update installation. then install the updates again one by one, so you can specifiy which update (if they are responyible) causes this.

Comment: I don't have system restore enabled, or I would have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all those recent updates one at a time, reboot in between each, until it loads the desktop properly. Use Programs and Features to do this.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Remove-an-update

.